# Document that can't be shared

Tags: mobile

I have created a pdf voucher/card to send to specific users, they store it on their phone and display it to get a concession. But it has occurred to me that they could pass on the pdf to others.

Is there an app or method which would allow me to send/install a document on a device that can not be shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do any of:

- Write a mobile App *for at least Android & iOS* to display the content of a custom or encrypted file format, (possibly having used some identifying features of the phone as the key).
- Send an encrypted PDF file requiring a key to unlock it - *a favourite trick that I have come across is to use the purchase credit card number as the key on the grounds that people are unlikely to share that.*
- You can make it harder to share by encrypting with a certificate (average users will know how to find the PDF but fewer will know how to find and identify the certificate.
- Customise the PDF with the end users Name, *possibly photo,* and Mobile Number - this will allow verification of the individual presenting the voucher at the time of presentation and *at least* give the recipient a little pause before sharing as they will know that they are traceable.